# How to parse a web site that uses `__dopostback` ajax call with curl and php

Tags: php, parsing, dopostback

Before someone says something or "jump," I would like to say that I have read:

- [Any idea on how to scrape pages which are behind __doPostBack('...');?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658801/any-idea-on-how-to-scrape-pages-which-are-behind-dopostback)
- [DotNetNuke, PHP, Simulating a remote postback using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896852/dotnetnuke-php-simulating-a-remote-postback-using-curl)
- [Scraping HTML with JavaScript postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216910/scraping-html-with-javascript-postbacks)
- [cURL post data to asp.net page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384655/curl-post-data-to-asp-net-page)
- http://techclimber.blogspot.com.es/2009/03/php-curl-and-aspnet.html

This is my function:

```
  function UolgetHtmlfromAjaxCallback($a_Params,$url) {

  $EVENTTARGET = $this->UolgetAtributoEventTarget($a_Params['s_EventTarget']);
  $s_smMaster = 'ctl00$cphSite$upModelo|'.$entries['target'];
  $VIEWSTATE = urlencode($a_Params['s_ViewState']);

  $options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "spider", // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'ct100%24smMaster='.urldecode($s_smMaster).
                          '&__EVENTTARGET='.urlencode($EVENTTARGET['target']).
                          '&__EVENTARGUMENT='.urlencode('').
                          '&__EVENTVALIDATION='.urlencode($s_Eventvalidation).
                          '&__VIEWSTATE='.$VIEWSTATE.
                          '&ct100%24txtBuscaNome='.$a_Params['ctl00_txtBuscaNome'].
                          '&__ASYNCPOST=true'
                          );

  $ch = curl_init( $url );
  curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
  $result = curl_exec ($ch);

  return $result;
  }
```

The `$VIEWSTATE` is okay, and the `$EVENTTARGET` is an array with these values:

```
Array ( 
 [id] =>          ctl00_cphSite_fichaTecnicaEditorial_rptCarrosFichaTecnica_ctl00_lbtnFichaTecnica 
 [target] => ctl00$cphSite$fichaTecnicaEditorial$rptCarrosFichaTecnica$ctl00$lbtnFichaTecnica )
```

I'm trying to use this code to scrape this website:

http://comparecar.uol.com.br/Modelo/Volvo-Xc60

And I get the website, but not the car's information.

I edit my own information.

I'm working with Tamper Data and I found that the post uses different parameters:

- `ctl00%24smMaster`
- `__EVENTTARGET`
- `__EVENTARGUMENT`
- `__VIEWSTATE`
- `__EVENTVALIDATION`
- `ctl00%24txtBuscaNome`
- `__ASYNCPOST`

And closes with an "="

Comment: http://256cats.com/scraping-asp-websites-php-dopostback-ajax-emulation/